# Pandas: equal values from different rows

Tags: python, pandas

Data Frame Example:

```
    A           B
0   2.234560    0.842407
1   0.842407    2.234560
2   3.183770    1.200300
3   1.200300    3.18377
```

I am trying to add a new column about the matching of values from 'A' and 'B' columns

Like this:

```
    A           B           C
0   2.234560    0.842407    A0 Matching with B1
1   0.842407    2.234560    B1 Matching with A0 
2   3.183770    1.200300    A2 Matching with B3
3   1.200300    3.183770    B3 Matching with A2
```

What is the right solution?

Comment: there is no logic.. ..A1,A3,B0,B2?..

Comment: Do A and B have identical values ordered differently?

Comment: @Anthony - Yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all values from `A` occur in `B` just in a different order you could easily use `dict`s for looking up the position:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'A': [2.234560, 0.842407, 3.183770, 1.200300], 
    'B': [0.842407, 2.234560, 1.200300, 3.183770]
})

# to account for gaps/duplicates in the index
lookup = dict(zip(df['B'], df.index))
df['C'] = [f'A{i} matches B{lookup[a]}' for a, i in zip(df['A'], df.index)]
print(df)
```

output:

```py
          A         B              C
0  2.234560  0.842407  A0 matches B1
1  0.842407  2.234560  A1 matches B0
2  3.183770  1.200300  A2 matches B3
3  1.200300  3.183770  A3 matches B2
```

Answer (score 0):

Some steps could be improved, but should work:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,1), columns=['A'])
df['B'] = df['A'].sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)


df_temp_a = df[['A']].assign(col_string_a = lambda x: 'A'+x.index.astype('str')).set_index('A')
df_temp_b = df[['B']].assign(col_string_b = lambda x: 'B'+x.index.astype('str')).set_index('B')

merged = df_temp_a.join(df_temp_b, how='inner')
merged['final_col'] = merged['col_string_a'] + " Matching with " + merged['col_string_b']
merged

df.merge(merged[['final_col']], how='left', left_on=['A'], right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

- [searchsorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) is centre of this solution
- need to prepare DF by sorting
- need to dereference from index return by `searchsorted()` to index of DF

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    A           B
0   2.234560    0.842407
1   0.842407    2.234560
2   3.183770    1.200300
3   1.200300    3.18377"""), sep="\s+")

# needs to be sorted for searchsorted()
df = df.sort_values("A")
# return of searchsorted() index into sorted array - put it through iloc[] to get DF index
df["C"] = df.apply(lambda r: f"B{r.name} matches A{df.iloc[df.A.searchsorted(r.B)].name}", axis=1)
df = df.sort_index()
```

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.23456 | 0.842407 | B0 matches A1 |
| 1 | 0.842407 | 2.23456 | B1 matches A0 |
| 2 | 3.18377 | 1.2003 | B2 matches A3 |
| 3 | 1.2003 | 3.18377 | B3 matches A2 |